# Why operator== is not overloaded?

Tags: c++

Why isn't the == operator getting properly overloaded (so that it can only return `true`)? I've tried without `*` but it does not help.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
    class alfa
    {
    public:
        int x;
        bool operator == (alfa  * &f)
        {
            return true;
        }   

    };

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //alfa alfa2;
    alfa * tab[2];
    tab[0] = new alfa;
    tab[1] = new alfa;
    if(tab[0] == tab[1])
    {
        std::cout << "tak";
    }

    scanf("%d");
}
```

Comment: Google Translate has improved recently.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Answer (score 4):

Your operator is a member of `alfa`, so it could not accept two `alfa` pointers, but rather, an `alpha` instance on the LHS and a pointer to `alpha` on the RHS.

If you wanted an operator to accept two `alpha` pointers, you would have to make it a non-member:

```
class alfa
{
public:
    int x;
};

bool operator == (const alpha* lhs, const alfa* rhs)
{
    return true;
}
```

However you are not allowed to overload comparison operators for built-in types such as pointers. You would have to provide an operator that can act on two instances:

```
bool operator == (const alpha& lhs, const alfa& rhs)
{
    return true;
}
```

Then, given two `alpha` pointers `a` and `b`, you can compare them like this:

```
*a == *b;
```

Comment: Note that overloading == for pointers is a really bad idea. I think he wanted to compare objects.

Comment: @zch It's not a bad idea, it's illegal.

Comment: @john Good point. I wasn't completely sure of there was an exception for pointers to user defined types, but I can't find any so I edited the answer.